# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character - BEHAVE, SELENIUM, PYCHARM

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pycharm, python-behave, charmap

When I want to create an html report with [behave.formatters]  for a test in selenium, I get this error in terminal: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character. I don't know why

when I enter the report I only receive this message "!DOCTYPE HTML"